# How to parse string in XML with spark xml parser in scala?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

What I try to do is to parse a String using XML parser.

I only find this way to parse using Spark in scala:

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .load("books.xml")
```

What I need to parse is a String, not a file

So, is there any option to load a String (not a file path)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an RDD from the string like below,

```
val xmlStringRDD = sc.parallelize(List("Your xml string"))
```

Then use the RDD as follows

```
val df = new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark.sqlContext(), xmlStringRDD);
```

where -  spark is the spark session(From Spark 2.0+).

> **Please Note:** This xmlRdd method was discussed to be deprecated, so for
>   now it works, might not in the future.

Comment: new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark, df.rdd)     in newer versions (without the sqlContext)